# Change numbers into Arabic words

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, ms-office

When I use a macro to change numbers into Arabic words, it displays characters like this:
��� �������.

I adjusted Windows language options and enabled Arabic in system locale with the beta Unicode support enabled.
In Windows everything is set to Arabic by default: Apps & websites, Regional Format, Keyboard (except display language and speech).
In Excel language options I set Arabic as preferred but not as display language.

I noticed when I copy and paste the code into any other module or text file, it pastes Arabic letters incorrectly like this: æÇÍÏ ÇËäÇä ËáÇË ÇÑÈÚ

Screenshot of the function outcome in xlsm file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0YR5.png

MS Office 2021

```vb
Public Function SpellIt(num_entry)
Dim LE
Dim PT
Dim iVal
Dim fFrac
Dim cDigit
Dim cFrac
Dim result
 
      LE = " جنيه "
      PT = " قرش  "
      iVal = Int(num_entry)
      cDigit = Digit_Translator(iVal)
      fFrac = Val(Right(Format(num_entry, "000000000000.00"), 2))
      cFrac = Digit_Translator(fFrac)
      If cDigit <> "" And fFrac > 0 Then result = cDigit & LE & " و " & cFrac & PT
      If cDigit <> "" And fFrac = 0 Then result = cDigit & LE
      If cDigit = "" And fFrac <> 0 Then result = cFrac & PT
      SpellIt = result
 
End Function
 
Private Function Digit_Translator(X)
Dim n
Dim c
Dim c1
Dim Digit1
Dim c2
Dim Digit2
Dim c3
Dim Digit3
Dim c4
Dim Digit4
Dim c5
Dim Digit5
Dim c6
Dim Digit6
 
      n = Int(X)
      c = Format(n, "000000000000")
      c1 = Val(Mid(c, 12, 1))
      Select Case c1
            Case Is = 1: Digit1 = "واحد"
            Case Is = 2: Digit1 = "اثنان"
            Case Is = 3: Digit1 = "ثلاث"
            Case Is = 4: Digit1 = "اربع"
            Case Is = 5: Digit1 = "خمس"
            Case Is = 6: Digit1 = "ست"
            Case Is = 7: Digit1 = "سبع"
            Case Is = 8: Digit1 = "ثمان"
            Case Is = 9: Digit1 = "تسع"
      End Select
 
      c2 = Val(Mid(c, 11, 1))
      Select Case c2
            Case Is = 1: Digit2 = "عشر"
            Case Is = 2: Digit2 = "عشرون"
            Case Is = 3: Digit2 = "ثلاثون"
            Case Is = 4: Digit2 = "اربعون"
            Case Is = 5: Digit2 = "خمسون"
            Case Is = 6: Digit2 = "ستون"
            Case Is = 7: Digit2 = "سبعون"
            Case Is = 8: Digit2 = "ثمانون"
            Case Is = 9: Digit2 = "تسعون"
      End Select
 
      If Digit1 <> "" And c2 > 1 Then Digit2 = Digit1 + " و" + Digit2
      If Digit2 = "" Then Digit2 = Digit1
      If c1 = 0 And c2 = 1 Then Digit2 = Digit2 + "ة"
      If c1 = 1 And c2 = 1 Then Digit2 = "احدى عشر"
      If c1 = 2 And c2 = 1 Then Digit2 = "اثنتى عشر"
      If c1 > 2 And c2 = 1 Then Digit2 = Digit1 + " " + Digit2
      c3 = Val(Mid(c, 10, 1))
      Select Case c3
            Case Is = 1: Digit3 = "مائة"
            Case Is = 2: Digit3 = "مئتان"
            Case Is > 2: Digit3 = Left(Digit_Translator(c3), Len(Digit_Translator(c3))) + "مائة"
      End Select
      If Digit3 <> "" And Digit2 <> "" Then Digit3 = Digit3 + " و" + Digit2
      If Digit3 = "" Then Digit3 = Digit2
 
      c4 = Val(Mid(c, 7, 3))
      Select Case c4
            Case Is = 1: Digit4 = "الف"
            Case Is = 2: Digit4 = "الفان"
            Case 3 To 10: Digit4 = Digit_Translator(c4) + " آلاف"
            Case Is > 10: Digit4 = Digit_Translator(c4) + " الف"
      End Select
      If Digit4 <> "" And Digit3 <> "" Then Digit4 = Digit4 + " و" + Digit3
      If Digit4 = "" Then Digit4 = Digit3
      c5 = Val(Mid(c, 4, 3))
      Select Case c5
            Case Is = 1: Digit5 = "مليون"
            Case Is = 2: Digit5 = "مليونان"
            Case 3 To 10: Digit5 = Digit_Translator(c5) + " ملايين"
            Case Is > 10: Digit5 = Digit_Translator(c5) + " مليونا"
      End Select
      If Digit5 <> "" And Digit4 <> "" Then Digit5 = Digit5 + " و" + Digit4
      If Digit5 = "" Then Digit5 = Digit4
 
      c6 = Val(Mid(c, 1, 3))
      Select Case c6
            Case Is = 1: Digit6 = "مليار"
            Case Is = 2: Digit6 = "ملياران"
            Case Is > 2: Digit6 = Digit_Translator(c6) + " مليارات"
      End Select
      If Digit6 <> "" And Digit5 <> "" Then Digit6 = Digit6 + " و" + Digit5
      If Digit6 = "" Then Digit6 = Digit5
      Digit_Translator = Digit6
 
End Function
```

Comment: Possibly an issue with your VBA code.  I certainly have no problem using VBA to place arabic characters into an Excel cell, even with all US English settings.

Comment: I've posted an Answer that worked in my case.

Comment: I do not have the Arabic SA language pack installed.

Comment: I used your code... thank you... but, if `iVal` and `num_entry` not **Dim**entioned as Double, it sometimes converts the number wrong... try with `2,495,159,565.00` for example...

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by installing the "Arabic SA" Language Pack from MS Office website.

Language pack downloaded from this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w1ka.png

Rebooted the PC and all I needed to do is to re calculate formulas (or just edit the cell and Click Enter without modifying anything).

This is so weird as the "Arabic Egypt" is the one installed in the windows.

Comment: There may be another solution, as I do not have the Arabic-SA language pack installed. (My installed languages are only English and  Hebrew.

Comment: I've done a lot of search. it's been 3 months with this issue. I know another person who has the same problem. in his case an excel file imported from a cloud ERP App.